# Save an existing file

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to save an existing pdf file? I have a pdf file's path and I want to save it to another location (not to move it, to copy). Is that doable using client side?

I tried with FileSaver.js:

```
saveAs('C:\\x\\y\\mydoc.pdf');
```

But I got an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No
>   function was found that matched the signature provided.

Do I have to do it with `blob`? Not sure how, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this on node.js?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 No...

Comment: Then you can't access files on your local computer. If that were possible, it would be a huge security hole don't you think?

Comment: As Derek said, this isn't possible in the browser. However, if your goal is to store data you can use a couple of different storage API's such as LocalStorage or cookies.

Comment: The only viable way to manipulate an outside context with JS is with NodeJS my friend.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 I don't want to edit an existing document, I just want to copy an existing document using a given path.

Comment: if you're trying to access files on your computer, use bash instead

Comment: @user3378165 It's like saying "I don't want to change things inside your house, I just want to move things around." Does that sound secure to you?